# How to capture captcha image object with DotNetBrowser

Tags: c, dotnetbrowser

The website we have shown on DotNetBrowser contains a captcha image element. What is the method of capturing this element image type in code element?

Web site address: https://paydas.its.gov.tr/hesap_yonetimi/giris

```
browserView = new WinFormsBrowserView(BrowserFactory.Create(BrowserType.LIGHTWEIGHT));
//...
browserView.Browser.SetSize(1024, 768); 
Bitmap screenshot = browserView.Browser.ImageProvider.GetImage() as Bitmap; 
DOMElement captchaElement = browserView.Browser.GetDocument().GetElementById("imgCaptcha"); 
pictureBox1.Image = screenshot?.Clone(captchaElement.BoundingClientRect, screenshot.PixelFormat);
```

This method does not work healthy.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution.

I've added the following code snippet after creating the Browser object.

```
int viewHeight = 20000;
            string[] switches = {
                    "--disable-gpu",
                    "--max-texture-size=" + viewHeight
            };
BrowserPreferences.SetChromiumSwitches(switches);
```